# Listing CloudFlare Zones via API

Tags: python, cloudflare

I'm struggling to get a python script to list CloudFlare zones via the API. I can successfully do this via a bash script with `curl`, but not via `requests` in Python.

This works.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer <SECRET>" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests

list_zones_url="https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones"
headers={'Authorization': "Bearer <SECRET>", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
resp=requests.get(list_zones_url,headers=headers)
print(resp)
```

It just hangs, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was the client was keeping the connection open.
`resp=requests.get(list_zones_url,headers=headers,timeout=5)` found my issue. Once I added that `print(resp)` returned `HTTP 200`